# Can a plain text file be corrupted or have a bug in the source?

Tags: plaintext

A rather simple question (I hope), but I am trying to learn more about plain text (in a UTF-8 mode) and how versatile it is. Most importantly, I'm reflecting on the usage of plain text in file systems such as `LaTeX` and similar processors.

They say that plain text is the most stable. Plain text is stable (by design). No need to worry about metadata being corrupted by a program like Word or similar WYSIWYGs; But I'm wondering:

- Can a plain text file be corrupted (in its source) or otherwise contain "Bugs?"
- If not, can someone explain how this works? Is plain text just parsed `I/O`?

This is an elementary question, I'm sure, but I'd like to understand how plain text functions inside a PC.

Comment: This question kind of makes me wonder... I want to say "of course, why wouldn't it be able to be corrupted?" but that is little more than a guess with my current knowledge. Say you completely lost power to your system mid-write. Would your file not have any issues?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Who are "they"?  Read the Wikipedia article on "Plain Text".
Any file can be corrupted by hardware failures.  But if a file has no metadata, the metadata cannot be corrupted by defects in the software that manipulates the file.